# python3.7 IndexError: list index out of range problem

Tags: python

I have faced an error `IndexError: list index out of range` when I ran `my_function(1, data)`. This function should find distance between given point `id` and other points.

Code:

```
import math 

p = []
point_dist = []
distance = 0
data = [[1, 5, 2], [2, 6, 2], [3, 7, 2], [4, 8, 2]]

def my_function(point_id,data):
    print(len(data))   
    p.append(data[point_id])
    data.pop(point_id)
    print(len(data))

    for i in range(0, 3, 1):
        for j in range(0, 3, 1):
            distance = math.sqrt(pow(p[0][j] - data[i][j], 2))
```

**Error**:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/ay/YandexDisk/python/1/untitled1.py", line 13, in <module>
    distance=math.sqrt(pow(p[0][j]-data[i][j],2))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

You never called your function `my_function` which populate you array `p`.
So your array is empty, and you can't access the `[0][j]` element.

Answer (score 0):

You only defined a function with the name `my_function()`
Then you have to call it first to get `p` `list`. Furthermore I prefer explicitely  returning `p` and `data`:

```
import math 

p=[]
point_dist=[]
distance=0
data=[[1,5,2],[2,6,2],[3,7,2],[4,8,2]]

def my_function(point_id, data):
    print(len(data))   
    p.append(data[point_id])
    data.pop(point_id)
    print(len(data))

    return p, data

p, data = my_function(1, data)

for i in range(0,3,1):
    for j in range(0,3,1):
     distance=math.sqrt(pow(p[0][j]-data[i][j],2))
```

**Out:**

```
4
3
```